# Making a 3d histogram from a datacube in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, histogram

So I currently have a datacube that is of dimensions 1014 by 1014 by 24. Essentially this is 24 images of size 1014 pixels by 1014 pixels. The 24 images were all taken at different times in the year

I would like to take a histogram for each of the 24 images and then plot them all as a 3d plot or 3d histogram where one of the axes is time. So essentially X = data value, y = time, z = count/frequency.

I was wondering how this could be done in matplotlib in python. I have tried mplot3d from https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html but this is for 3D histograms from 2D data.

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you want something that looks like this: https://plotly.com/python/violin/#ridgeline-plot ? I.e. 24 one-dimensional histograms behind each other in shown in some kind of three-dimensional way?

Comment: @Noskario This could work, however it does seem difficult to tell if one histogram peaks higher than another. I will also need to compare to a previous set of 26 images (for a total of 50 histograms) so not sure if it will become messy. I will give this a shot though, thank you!

Comment: If you need to stick to matplotlib-style, the package joyplot seems to be nice. I played around a bit and it works, you can even make the violin-plots histograms.

Comment: @ProtonChain: can you self-answer with your rough solution?